# Unexpected BigQuery "Error: Field 'job_id' not found in table" even if job_id is not used

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a complex BigQuery query that gives me strange errors. I has nested joins with three large tables and several partitions are included for one of the tables using table_date_range().

When the innermost select clause includes too many partitions I unexpectedly get the error below, **even if there is no field called job_id anywhere in the query**. The query works just fine if I only include one or sometimes two partitions (depending on size?).

> **Error:** Field 'job_id' not found in table 'project:dataset.table_20160119'; did you mean 'app_id'?

I cannot post the full query because of sensitive data, but the structure is as follows:

```
SELECT
  fields
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM
          TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project1:dataset1.table1_],
            TIMESTAMP('2016-01-19'),
            TIMESTAMP('2016-01-24'))
        WHERE
          conditions
        ) alias_1
      ) alias_2
    FULL OUTER JOIN EACH (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM 
        [project2:dataset2.table2_20160124]
      WHERE
        conditions
      ) alias3
    ON alias2.user_id = alias3.user_id
  ) alias4
LEFT JOIN
  [project2:dataset3.table3_20160124] alias5
ON
  alias4.user_id = alias5.user_id
GROUP BY
  fields
ORDER BY
  field
```

Comment: 1) is `job_id` a field in any of the tables, if yes which? 2) when you say you are not posting the full query, does that mean you are not really using `select *`? Can you indicate where you are using partitions? Your problems sounds familiar to something I have been experiencing, and iIrc, in that case the 'solution' is to provide aliases for certain fields. (They can be eponymous.)

Comment: 1) Thanks for the tip. I just checked, and yes, `job_id` is present in the table used with `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()` and when comparing the different days there has been a schema change and job_id only exists for some days
2) I've removed some fields, but I am actually using * on all the inner clauses

Comment: I will try to manually select fields instead of using * for the table with the schema change and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution. Apparently there has been a schema change in `table1` within the date range I am using, and the field `job_id` only exists for some of the dates. Even if this field is not used, it makes BigQuery throw the error.

The problem was solved by selecting columns manually for the affected table, instead of using *.